# Using aasm gem outside of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Can anyone help me on how the aasm gem can be used outside of models like in service objects?I need to know the current user in one of the gaurd blocks so I need to move it outside of a model

```
aasm.attribute_name :state

event :approve do
      transitions from: :approval_pending, to: :approved, if: :admin?
end

private 

def admin?
# check if current user is admin
end
```

Comment: Couldn't you keep the check for the admin permission on wathever method you call the `approve` on the controller or service object? What would the downside be?

Comment: I cant keep the check on the controller or service object as there will be different events called and not all of them require admin permissions.